Visual Studio 17.10.3 git error "Failed to fetch from remote repository"
Before anyone gets on my nerves, I have already checked this post (visual studio 16.11.5 git-errors, failed to fetch from the remote repository) and tried the recommended solution.
I updated my Visual Studio version. I hadn't fetched for a while, so this issue might have been present in a few previous versions as well.
Now, I receive the following output:"Error encountered while fetching: Failed to fetch from the remote repository. See the Output window for more details.
Failed to fetch from the remote repository. See the Output window for more details."
By the way, this message is from the Output window...
Things I have already tried, without success:

Repaired Visual Studio using the Visual Studio Installer
Rolled back to the previous version using the Visual Studio Installer
Installed git-credential-manager.exe and configured it in the git config
Disabled the credential-manager in the git config

Which is also confusing me alot is, that the git fetch command in the command line works, but mabye this is also true for the old post.

Install git bash in your PC. Go to your working directory, right click and select open git bash. Run the git fetch command from the terminal and see if it's working or not

@shafeeq it works like that, atleast i think so. Do you get a respone from the shell, if it has worked and you are already have the newest version?
